# Postgres database connection not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

I'm trying to connect with my database postgres, using the node-postgres package, but my connection is not working. I set every parameter that needs to stablish the connection, and even with all being set, I'm not receiving the message in the log that the database is connected. What I'm missing?

My code:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'clinica-veterinaria',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432,
  })

pool.on('connect',() => {
    console.log('Conexão estabelecida com sucesso')
});

module.exports = {
    query: (text,params) => pool.query(text,params),
}
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const routes = require('./routes')
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.urlencoded({  extended:true }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());

app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Acessar http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('Servidor executando na porta 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you create the pool, I don't see you connecting to the Postgre Server. Check [this document](https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool#new-pool) for more info.

Try this:

```js
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'clinica-veterinaria',
    password: 'admin',
    port: 5432,
});

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack)
    }
    // Do what you have to do with the pool client now
}
```

Comment: Happy to help 

Comment: documentation hyperlink not working anymore @Eranga Heshan